# CreateNewUser() firebase method is returning nil in the closure for user uid

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to authenticate users. But the `createNewUser()` firebase method is returning nil in the closure for user?.user.uid and thus I cannot add the data under the correct node.

**Bellow is my user creation method:**

```
 func createNewUser(email: String, password: String) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
        if error == nil && user != nil { //user create works
            print(user, "<-- User Created (user)")
        } else { //user not create
            print("Error creating user: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        //database integration
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let usersRef = ref.child("users2")

        let uid = user?.user.uid
        print(email, "<-- email")

        print(uid, "<-- this is uid")
        let newUserRef = usersRef.child(uid!)//This fails because UID is nil
        newUserRef.setValue(["email": self.emailTextField.text!, "password": self.passwordTextField.text!, "fullName": self.fullNameTextField.text!, "username": self.usernameTextField.text!])

        print(email, "<--- this is emaiL??")

    } //end of create user

}
```

***How do I fix this?***

Comment: Sign in with given username and password after passing no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[When I look at the docs for Firebase's "`createUserWithEmail:password:completion:`" method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account), it looks like you get an `authResult, error` back from `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail:...`.

And from that, to get the user, you'd do:

```
func createNewUser(email: String, password: String) {
      Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in

      guard let authResult = authResult, error == nil else {
         print("Error creating user: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
         return // an error!
      }

      if let user = authResult.user {
         if let uid = user.uid {
            print("uid is \(uid)")
         }
         if let email = user.email {
            print("email is \(email)")
         }
      }
      ...
      ...
      ...
```